# codeigniter has foreach error

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

Hey im using codeigniter and i got this error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: slide
>
> Filename: daxili/slider.php
>
> Line Number: 3
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: D:\OpenServer\domains\vtgroup\application\views\daxili\slider.php
>
> Line: 3
>   Function: _error_handler

**controller:**

```
public function index() {
    $data['slide'] = $this->slide->get_slide();
    $this->load->view('daxili/slider', $data);
}
```

**view:**

```
<?php foreach($slide as $key => $val) : ?>                  
    <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="10" data-slice2-rotation="-15" data-slice1-scale="1.5" data-slice2-scale="1.5">
        <div class="sl-slide-inner">
            <img class="bg-img wow fadeInUp" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/img/slides/<?php echo $val['slide_image']; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**model:**

```
public function get_slide(){
    $query = $this->db->get('slide');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: what's the output of your get_slide method ?

Comment: controller:

public function index() {

            $data['slide'] = $this->slide->get_slide();

            $this->load->view('daxili/slider', $data);
        }

Comment: the output array i mean, check if it a valid array

Comment: Array ( [slide] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => birinci [slide_image] => 1.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [title] => ikinci [slide_image] => 2.jpg ) ) )

Comment: class Slide extends CI_Controller {

     public function index() {
   
   $data['slide'] = $this->slide->get_slide();
   
   print_r(($data));
  }

Comment: @Subhan in view `print_r($slide)`  and post the data

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: slide

Filename: daxili/slider.php

Line Number: 2

Backtrace:

File: D:\OpenServer\domains\vtgroup\application\views\daxili\slider.php
Line: 2
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\OpenServer\domains\vtgroup\application\views\index.php
Line: 28
Function: view

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the entire Model and Controller classes? It definitely looks like your `get_slide()` call is returning something `undefined` - perhaps a DB connection isn't being made or the model isn't being loaded in your controller.

You could also check `$this->db->error();` in your Model class just in case.

**Update 2**: You are autoloading your model as `slide`. Is it possible that CodeIgniter will not extract the `$data['slide']` into a global variable because it collides with an auto-loaded identifier?

Try renaming it `$data['slideArray']` in the controller and doing `foreach($slideArray as $key => $val)` in the view?

Comment: This is model (autoload {'slide_model' => 'slide'}): 
<?php
class Slide_model extends CI_Model{
public function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
}
    
public function get_slide(){
    $query = $this->db->get('slide');
    return $query->result_array();
}
}

**and Controller:**

<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Slide extends CI_Controller {
   
public function index() {
       
            $data['slide'] = $this->slide->get_slide();

            $this->load->view('daxili/slider', $data);
 }
    }

Comment: Model is autoloading. Because controller is usefull. only view is useless:

Comment: Array ( [slide] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => birinci [slide_image] => 1.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [title] => ikinci [slide_image] => 2.jpg ) ) )   
     
class Slide extends CI_Controller { public function index() { $data['slide'] = $this->slide->get_slide(); print_r(($data)); }

Comment: What happens if you set `$data['test']='Test String';` in your controller and then echo that in the view above the foreach?

Comment: this is not working.  $this->load->view('daxili/slider', $data);

Comment: i use click function in navigation bars. #home, #slide and etc. is this problem?

Comment: HTML classes and JavaScript should not be an issue since the view code is interpreted on the backend only.

Comment: Try my new suggestion?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: slideArray

Filename: daxili/slider.php

Line Number: 3

Backtrace:

File: D:\OpenServer\domains\vtgroup\application\views\daxili\slider.php
Line: 3
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\OpenServer\domains\vtgroup\application\views\index.php
Line: 28
Function: view

Comment: which versions of CodeIgniter and PHP are you using?

Comment: Could you try assigning the return value of `get_slide()` to a temp variable and then setting the `data` property to this variable? Like this: `$slideResult = $this->slide->get_slide(); $data['slide'] = $slideResult;`

Comment: PHP 5.4 version and codeigniter last version. i used this:

Comment: $slideResult = $this->slide->get_slide();
$data['slide'] = $slideResult;

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: slide

Filename: daxili/slider.php

Line Number: 3

Backtrace:

File: D:\OpenServer\domains\vtgroup\application\views\daxili\slider.php
Line: 3
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\OpenServer\domains\vtgroup\application\views\index.php
Line: 28
Function: include

Comment: Have you changed the view engine? Used any hooks? Changed/used the Loader class? Added anything in the `core` directory?

Comment: İ change view file. İ`m not added anything in the core directory. İ`m not used any hook. There isn`t difference

Comment: **I founded problem. thanks. Problem is so simple. only i add in controller file all view file. it is my false. thanks all of them**

Comment: So when I asked you to post your full controller code, you just posted part of it? There was more code in your controller file?

Comment: There was some part php file in controller. now there is only 1 php file in controller. And i wrote who is problem file. problem file is only this file (this code is full code. have not another function or etc. ). i change another method. And now this file is working :) .